# Which of Magic's 1v1 tournament constructed formats is most popular?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The formats I'm interested in are:

- Vintage
- Legacy
- Modern
- Pioneer
- Standard

(I'm not interested in Archenemy, Commander, 2HG, etc)

Is there some way to rank these five formats in terms of popularity? If so, how?

Comment: How are you defining “most popular”? Most number of people who play that format, how many games of that format get played per year, etc?

Comment: @GendoIkari I imagine most definitions will yield the same result (if they don't, that itself would be interesting). If it matters then I'd go with "how many games of that format are getting played per year", although if that data is not available then I'm also interested in other definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my answer I only discuss the large, official tournaments like Pro Tours and Grand Prix, since they are the only ones with readily available data. Everyone can register a sanctioned event of their own, and there doesn't seem to be an overview with attendance numbers or format used. The best numbers to obtain would probably come from WotC's own market research, but they're never going to publish that in any detail.

In terms of all-time number of events and players, Grand Prix are the most important event type. Perhaps unsurprisingly, Limited and Standard are the most common formats, accounting for 446 of total 654 GPs.

- Limited: 290 events, 294,076 players
- Standard: 156 events, 172,203 players
- Modern: 76 events, 115,227 players
- Legacy: 31 events, 47,223 players
- Pioneer: 5 events (3 played, 2 planned), 4276 players
- Vintage does not have any GP or PT events.

Going by average number of attendees per event, the ranking looks almost inverted:

- Legacy: 1,523
- Modern: 1,516
- Pioneer 1,425
- Standard: 1,103
- Limited: 1,014

The inversion in ranking of the non-Pioneer formats from total numbers to average numbers per event seems to show that the less-supported formats still have a dedicated player base that makes use of any opportunity to play competitively, while the more supported formats spread out their player base over more events.

Pioneer meanwhile does show a strong popularity, going by average number of players per event. Since it's a brand-new format with all events played in 2020, only time will tell if its popularity is sustainable, or if it's just due the novelty of the format that will eventually wear off.

Pro Tours are harder to quantify by format since they are mostly played in mixed formats, but since their total numbers are much lower and proportionally similar to GPs, they don't change the overall picture. Combinations of Standard and Limited formats account for the plurality of players and events.

In terms of prize pool, however, PTs are much more significant. GPs range from $10K to $80K, while PTs range from $100K to $850K, an order of magnitude more.

Sources:

[Mtg Pro Tour,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering_Pro_Tour) [List of events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_Pro_Tour_events)

[MtG Grand Prix,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Prix_(Magic:_The_Gathering)) 
 [List of events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_Grand_Prix_events)

Comment: Would it be possible add the average/median frequency of time between events per format? The number might vary wildly between different years, but a rough ballpark would be nice.

Comment: @L.P. Surely it's possible. The first GP was in '97, so the average per year would be number of events divided by 23. I don't quite see the value of that number though, maybe you could explain?

Comment: Is there any indication that WotC organizes these events based on the format's popularity (as opposed to their lucrativeness)?

Comment: limited has the appeal of not having to bring your own deck. Legacy and vintage are really stymied by the reserve list, a lot of people would love to get into those formats.